# Unable to import .class files from java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project which includes settings, bin, src, .classpath, .project.
I am trying to run this project in eclipse, so I import this project. Now in eclipse I can see   `src` which includes `(default package)` and `com.mjm.transactions`,`(default package)` includes all .java files, in `com.mjm.transactions` it is supposed to exist all .class files in `transactions` folder which I cant see in eclipse, and so there is error on `import com.mjm.transactions.myclass;` of cannot be resolved.

I also used 'Add class folder' in myProject->properties->Library ->**myclass.zip** but it is not importing `myclass.class`, if I use organize imports in eclipse it resolves this error and adds `Reference Libraries/myClass.zip/default package/myclass.class`  but now giving me error **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mjm/transactions/myclass** when I run it.

Where is the problem, pls help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source files are in the `com.mjm.transactions` package, then they should be placed in `src/com/mjm/transactions` in order for Eclipse to recognize that they are part of the `com.mjm.transactions` package. Move all the `.java` files in the default package to the `com.mjm.transactions` package within Eclipse and it should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you define the Java build path. Keep Output Output folder to /bin. All the compiled files (.class files) should exist in the bin folder. so that those will be available in classpath.